# Python: Gauss-Newton Method only correct for 1st iteration

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

I am trying to find the near-intersection points of *n* circles in Python using the Gauss-Newton Method. The goal here is when given points *(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (xn, yn)* and radii *R1, R2, ..., Rn*, the Gauss-Newton Method is used to find the point for which the sum of the squared distances to the *n* circles is minimized.

This is an iterative method such that we start with an initial vector *v0 = [0, 0]*. It is completely correct for the first iteration, but subsequent iterations are incorrect. I cannot find the mistake in the code:

```
solutions = []
rmse = []

vk = [[0], [0]] # initial is set here
x = [0, 1, 0]
y = [1, 1, -1]
radii = [1, 1, 1]

iterations = 3

base_str_x = "(x _xi) / sqrt((x xi)^2 + (y yi)^2)"
base_str_y = "(y _yi) / sqrt((x xi)^2 + (y yi)^2)"
base_str_rk = "sqrt((x xi)^2 + (y yi)^2) Ri K"


it = 0
while it < iterations:
    i = 0
    A = []
    while i < len(x):
        A.append(["", ""])
        A0_str = base_str_x.replace(" xi", "%+f" % (x[i]))
        A0_str = A0_str.replace(" yi", "%+f" % (y[i]))
        A0_str = A0_str.replace("_xi", "%+f" % (x[i] * -1))
        A[i][0] = float(f(vk[0][0], A0_str, vk[1][0]))
        A1_str = base_str_y.replace(" xi", "%+f" % (x[i]))
        A1_str = A1_str.replace(" yi", "%+f" % (y[i]))
        A1_str = A1_str.replace("_yi", "%+f" % (y[i] * -1))
        A[i][1] = float(f(vk[0][0], A1_str, vk[1][0]))
        i += 1

    i = 0
    rk = []
    while i < len(x):
        rk.append([""])
        r0_str = base_str_rk.replace(" xi", "%+f" % (x[i]))
        r0_str = r0_str.replace(" yi", "%+f" % (y[i]))
        r0_str = r0_str.replace("Ri", "%+f" % (radii[i] * -1))
        rk[i][0] = float(f(vk[0][0], r0_str, vk[1][0]))
        i += 1

    lhs = np.matmul(map(list, zip(*A)), A)
    rhs = -np.matmul(map(list, zip(*A)), rk)
    vk = np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(lhs), rhs)
    solutions.append(vk)
```

This code computes *A = Dr(x, y)*, which is defined as:

[image]

Then it solves the equation:

[image]

for `vk`.

The function `f` is a "universal function" that is used to compute each element of `A`. Any help finding why subsequent iterations after the first are incorrect would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons why this is happening:

1. The signs inside the parentheses are wrong. To account for this, multiply `x[1]` by `-1` inside every term. For example `A0_str = A0_str.replace(" yi", "%+f" % (y[i] * -1))`
2. Error propagation. The resultant matrix gives a result that is accurate up to less decimal places than the conversion to `float` in the subsequent iteration.

While the first issue can be solved easily, the second issue cannot. Using `Decimal` is not supported by `matmul` and gives a `TypeError`. The `float64` or `float128` data types do not appear increase the precision.